# Array en Java: Rellenar con asteriscos distribución de datos

Tags: java, array

a todos, gracias por leer, estoy realizando un ejercicio donde en un **array** de objetos llamado `calificacionesExamen` de **11 posiciones** para almacenar los valores del mismo en una columna con el resultado abajo de salida por consola.

Como hago para completar la información de estos datos, por ejemplo con un valor de 25 del array, se asigna a la fila `20-29:` un **asterico** por cada valor agregado.

**Ejemplo**: Si el array contiene 3 valores entre 0 y 9, se suman tres (***) a la fila: 00-09:

Mi codigo se quedo aca:

```
public class GraficoBarrarMejorado {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[]calificacionesExamen= {84,25,14,36,97,85,14,11,28,100,34};
    System.out.println("Distribucacion de Calificaciones de Test");
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<calificacionesExamen.length;i++) {

        if(i==10) System.out.printf("%5d: ",100); //DIGITOS PARA IMPRIMIR EN JAVA   
        else System.out.printf("%02d-%02d: ",i * 10, i * 10 + 9);

                    System.out.println();

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: puedes poner una mejor explicación pues no se entiende que es lo que buscas lograr

Comment: Hola DavElSanto, lo que busco lograr es que los datos del array sumen un * (asterisco) a la salida por consola del rango. Ejemplo: calificacionesExamen[i]=50; Entonces ese valor 50 almacenar un asterico en la salida por consola del rango: Numeros entre 40 y 50: *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregarle un ciclo para que recorra el **array** y si el numero que esta recorriendo esta dentro del rango de las calificaciones imprima un " * "

```
int j;
for (j=0; j<calificacionesExamen.length ;j++ ) {
    if (calificacionesExamen[j]>=i*10 && calificacionesExamen[j]<=(i*10) + 9){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

y luego un salto de linea al finalizar

```
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Es correcto Fabian Vargas. Gracias